# Real Analysis, continuity at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. 
$$A=\{y\in\mathbb{R}: y=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)\}$$ 
for some sequence $x_n\to\infty$.

The set $A$ is connected. Please suggest hints.

Comment: Hint: take $y_1, y_2 \in A$, $(x_n^1), (x_n^2)$ suitable sequences. Then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem...

Comment: Thank you so much. I will work on your suggestions. Is there a counter example to show that A is not compact?

Comment: The "for some sequence ..." should be included in your set brackets.

Comment: The definition of A does not demand that y belongs to image of f. So what is the necessity to apply Intermediate Value Theorem? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \liminf_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\beta = \limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$. Then $A=[\alpha, \beta]$ if $f$ is bounded. If $f$ is unbounded then $A$ is not compact since it will be unbounded itself.

Comment: Sorry. I am unable to find a continuous function on R with limit supremum infinite and limit infimum finite as x tends to infinity. Please help.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x(1+\sin x)$.

Comment: The function is x(1+sin x). Am I correct??

Comment: For arctan x, the set A is the whole real line R. Am I correct?? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not able to ascertain A when f=e^x or arctan x. Kindly help please.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, \infty \}$, then $A=\{L\}$ is a compact subset of the extended real line.